# How to attach jquery click event handler on canvas circle to display pop up box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have a pop function with a notification icon like facebook. But when we click on that notification icon, the pop up should be displayed. For these I need to attach an event handler. My partial code is here:

```
$("#comment_save").click(function(){
cmt++;
//drawing circle
context.beginPath();
context.arc(90,60,10,0,2*Math.PI);
context.lineWidth = 2;//for border thikness
context.fillStyle = 'green';
context.fill();
context.strokeStyle = 'gray';
context.stroke();
//drawing text
context.font="15px Georgia";
context.fillStyle = 'yellow';
if(cmt<=9){
cmt="0"+cmt;
}
context.fillText(cmt,80,65);
$(".popup").hide();
});
```

Comment: Look over here: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: which part is not working?

Answer (score 1):

In canvas one does not operate with DOM elements, that is why you can't attach to anything that is on canvas.

For canvas we only have coordinates. We attach click event to canvas element and read coordinates, where click was made. When we draw something on canvas, we just remember that, and when click is made, we search if coordinates of anything we have drawn on canvas matches coordinates of click that is made.

Look at example http://jsfiddle.net/Deele/N2uX5/

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas'),
    context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    clickableAreas = [];
$(function() {
    $("#comment_save").click(function(){
        //drawing circle
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(90,60,10,0,2*Math.PI);
        context.lineWidth = 2;//for border thikness
        context.fillStyle = 'green';
        context.fill();
        context.strokeStyle = 'gray';
        context.stroke();
        //drawing text
        context.font="15px Georgia";
        context.fillStyle = 'yellow';
        context.fillText('1',80,65);
        $("#myCanvas").click(function(e){
            var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft,
                y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
            console.log('Click at ['+x+'|'+y+']');
            if (coordinatesWithin(x, y, 90 - 10, 90 + 10, 60 - 10, 60 + 10)) {
               alert('circle was clicked');
            }
        });
    });
});
function coordinatesWithin(x,y, minX, maxX, minY, maxY) {
    return (x >= minX && x <= maxX && y >= minY && y <= maxY);
}
```

There are tutorials out there, how to automate this process and have better control over this, like http://pterkildsen.com/2013/06/28/create-a-html5-canvas-element-with-clickable-elements/

If you have tons of things drawn in canvas, with detailed shapes (that are not square), with many layers, and you would like to be able to know which one was clicked, I would use approach with coordinate array, where all coordinates are stored and each thing, when drawn on canvas layer by layer, takes ownership of specific pixel and when everything is drawn on canvas, you will end with array with coordinates, where each coordinate has specific owner, defined by some sort of ID, and array with callback functions, identified by ID. When canvas is clicked, you just find coordinate in first array and trigger function from second array.